# MythTV: SSD recording - HDD storage

Tags: linux, media, video-capture, mythtv

Does anyone know if it's possible to configure MythTV to store on a local SSD while recording, but on a HDD (alt. locally mounted network disk) after the recording has finished?
(I'm using MythTV 0.25)

Comment: Only programming related questions are on-topic here.

Comment: @ArjunShankar: Since MythTV is a PVR, configuring it is technically also called "programming" :-).

Comment: Seems like the answer turns out to be about programming after all... But I think I can handle it from here. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest path is probably as follows:

- Set up your SSD and HDD as storage volumes
- Set your storage volume priority to use the SSD for recording
- Create a user job that moves recordings to your HDD when done

Depending on your backend setup (hard drive layout, number of tuners etc.) using an SSD for recordings may not make much difference - your tuner bandwidth & other I/O from the disks would need to exceed what your HDD is capable of for an SSD to make a difference to recordings. An SSD would probably be good for your DB/OS though, as evidenced from the MythTV mailing lists.

Comment: Thanks! I'll see if I can figure this out this weekend.

I chose the SSD setup because I imagined it might be cruel to the HDD to watch ongoing recordings while at the same time recording several shows in parallel with multiple tuners. ;)

Comment: Seems like writing a script for a user job can make the copying quite easy.

Comment: (I hit return a bit to early...)
It would have been nice though if Myth had kept it on the SSD only while recording... But I want to store them outside Myth anyway, so no great loss there. ;)